# jquery smartbanner without apple smartbanner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I am using http://jasny.github.io/jquery.smartbanner/  but the default apple smartbanner is showing so there are two, I only want the one I created using that plugin and not the apple one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which browser/device do you see the double banner?

Comment: I have the same issue. I see double smart banner on iPhone 5 safari. When tried on iPhone 5 chrome, only one banner was seen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise removing Apple's `apple-itunes-app` meta tag and implementing something that is completely standalone instead, e.g. [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js).

`smartbanner.js` also gives you more flexibility and the most recent release also allows advanced filtering as per platform.